# Issue sending text to WebElement through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get this code to work, but it isn't. I enter manually and it works but not when I automate it.

```
import selenium
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
num = 1
while num != 1000:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://mobile.brawlhalla.com/?kid=1415HM')
    id_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
    id_box.send_keys(str(num) +'@1.com')
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-id-6zgew9flrfn')
    login_button.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
    num = num + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably invoke `WebDriverWait` before trying to send keys to the `input` field that you locate. This may help:

```
import selenium
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

num = 1
while num != 1000:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://mobile.brawlhalla.com/?kid=1415HM')

    # invoke WebDriverWait before sending keys to email field
    id_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))
    id_box.send_keys(str(num) +'@1.com')
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-id-6zgew9flrfn')
    login_button.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
    num = num + 1
```